# Installed Win7 SDK. Can't find winDbg

Tags: windows-7, windbg, bsod

I installed everything including the debugging tools. I've looked through the Microsoft SDK folder and couldn't find anything that resembled winDbg or an installer for it.

Anyone?

Edit: I'm trying to use a dump file to figure out why I had a BSOD. Will this site give me the same information as winDbg? http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=analyze

Edit 2: I think the sdk did not install correctly. So I'm working on that now. I'm pretty sure what the sdk I downloaded included debugging tools(winDbg). http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8279

Edit 3: Installed the sdk correctly and all is well.

Comment: If you are new to WinDbg, the following video (and links to earlier ones) will help in learning how to set it up. http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-87-Windows-8-1-Update

Comment: You can also get WinDbg from here: http://www.codemachine.com/downloads.html

Comment: How did you get this to work? I've just done the same thing and checked 'Debugging Tools for Windows' - but there's nothing called 'windbg' installed :( I can't see 'Windows SDK' in my installed programs to remove it, either. :( All this talk of xcopy deployment. But I can't get to the exe! ;)

Comment: Found it. I didn't read the accepted answer properly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I uninstalled the 2010 C++ x86 and x64 redistributables. This allowed me to install the SDK completely along with the redistributables I just uninstalled. I found winDbg here: C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64).

This can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik it is part of DDK now,
Sdk doesn't have it.

Comment: In my case (Windows 7 x64) this answer is correct, the 64 bit version of windbg is in C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\Debuggers\

Answer (score 1):

I have VS 2017 Enterprise installed.
The Visual Studio Installer allowed me to install the Windows 10 SDK.
For me, the Visual Studio Installer is located at:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe
You can run this and click 'Modify' and then the 'Individual Components' tab.
Find the Windows SDK you are wanting installed (ex. Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.0))
Once that is installed, you will probably need to go to Control Panel and select 'Uninstall a program'.
Find the Windows 10 SDK in the list and click 'change'.
This will let you select to install 'Debugging Tools for Windows'.
You can also enable/install other features you might want such as the performance tools.